# My python script to download a youtube video's audio doesn't work as intended

Tags: python, audio, youtube

I'm trying to make this python script work:

The script should download the youtube video link's Audio, the link is saved in a .txt file in the same folder as the script

when i run the script it doesn't do anything has anyone got a clue?

```
import pafy

# opening the text file which contains all the links
file = open('list.txt', 'r')

# loop through each link in the file
for line in file:

    # Assign link to "url" variable
    url = line

    try:
        # Passing link to pafy
        video = pafy.new(url)

        # extracting the best available audio
        bestaudio = video.getbestaudio()
        print(video.title)

        # downloading the extracted audio
        bestaudio.download()

    # move to next link if the video is removed in the youtube platform
    except:
        pass

# close the text file
file.close()
```

The youtube video i watched to get this code is:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ob8pSr9Vxs0&ab_channel=AkshayKGowda"

The scrpit is not downloading any file even if the .txt contains valid youtube links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it!

So basically i modified the pafy file "backend_youtube_dl.py" as was said in the github pull request that never made it into the merge at "https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/pull/288/files".

changed the line 53,54

```
self._likes = self._ydl_info['like_count']
self._dislikes = self._ydl_info['dislike_count']
```

into

```
self._likes = self._ydl_info.get('like_count', 0)
self._dislikes = self._ydl_info.get('dislike_count', 0)
```

done this my code didn't give errors anymore and downloaded the audio files as expected.

I suppose this problem is caused by youtube removing the ability to see dislikes in all videos idk tho just my hypothesis.

Thanks to John Gordon for guiding me!

Answer (score 0):

```
except:
    pass
```

This is a very poor way of handling exceptions.  If anything at all goes wrong in the `try` block, it will simply be ignored and you will never know what happened.

Change it to this:

```
except Exception as ex:
    print('Caught exception', ex)
```

So at least you will know what error is happening.  Maybe it is some error you never thought of.

Comment: Thank you, i changed it and it gives me this error whatever link i use:
Caught exception 'like_count'

Comment: Temporarily remove the exception handling altogether (take out the `try` and `except` statements).  That will show the entire error traceback.  Sounds like some error is happening inside the `pafy` or `bestaudio` modules.

Comment: it's trying to return Pafy(url, basic, gdata, size, callback, ydl_opts=ydl_opts)

and fetching the basics it gives this error: self._likes = self._ydl_info['like_count']
KeyError: 'like_count'

Comment: This is a known (and apparently fixed) bug in the pafy module https://github.com/mps-youtube/pafy/issues/287.  What version of pafy do you have?

Comment: i installed pafy using the command pip install pafy today